# Find out if multiple documents were uploaded or just one

Tags: 2013

Is there anyway I can find out if a user uploaded multiple documents or just one document to a specified list, possibly within event receivers or any other way? (SharePoint 2013)

Comment: Do you want to know how many documents the user has uploaded as attachment to different list items of a list or just a true/false , true being only 1 document attached?

Comment: Please add more details to this question for us to be able to help you :)

Comment: I believe by "documents" he means actual documents in a document library, not list item attachments. I don't suppose Event Receivers will be of user here, because I think they only know about one list item at a time. Can you give us more details on what exactly you're trying to do here, there may be other approaches.